# Picture makes the App slow?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I use a background for my Android App it begins to lagg. I'm just using :

```
android:background = "@drawable/picture_here"
```

When I click on a button it takes 2min till it reacts.
Is it because of the Emulator or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What size is your picture?

Comment: 2560x1600 . Can it be cause of the Reso. ? And which size could be better ?

Comment: btw, the emulator is notoriously slow. To test performance you'd better use a real phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the emulator is slow. See if you can run intel processor powered emulator to increase its performance. Also see if the image s of the appropriate format. Because heavy formats like bitmaps can be of large size. So make sure that the image is not too big.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator is slow. Also you are displaying image that is too big. Take a look at image's size which must be loaded into RAM at runtime. If you are loading it into frame that is smaller than image itself it must recalculate size of it. (take DPI of device into account) Try smaller your image and run it on real device or e.g. Genymotion.

Answer (score -1):

-Go to http://www.genymotion.com/ download the genymotion emulator
-make an account for free
-install what device you needed and test again the app